# edit filehandling Visual C++

Tags: c, file-io

So I got a problem of editing in file handling using visual C++.The code I have now will show what's inside the file and when editing it, you have to retype all the contains of the file including the ones you edit.. But my professor said it was not editing but overwriting the original file..so I was wondering how will I EDIT the contains of the file without rewriting the whole statement.

```
   void edit()
    {
        char choice;
        char newdata[1000];
        char previousdata[1000];
        char filename [1000];
        int count =0;
        printf("Example: D:/sample.txt");
        printf("Enter filename:");
        scanf("%s",&filename);
        fp=fopen(filename,"r");

        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to open....\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Success in opening file...\n\n");
            int c;

            c = getc(fp);
            while(c!=EOF)
            {
                printf("%c",c);
                previousdata[count] = c;
                c = getc(fp);
                count++;
            }

        }
        fclose(fp);

        printf("\nPlease Type the new statement");
        printf("\nInput Statement:\n");
        scanf("%s",&newdata);


        printf("\nDo you want to save the changes?");
        printf("\n Press[Y] YES \t\t Press[N] NO");
        printf("\n Your choice:");
        scanf("%s",&choice);

        if(choice == 'Y'|| choice == 'y')
        {
            fp =fopen(filename,"w");
            fprintf(fp,"%s",newdata);
            fclose(fp);
            main();
        }
        else if(choice == 'N'||choice == 'n')
        {
            system("CLS");
            main();
        }       

    }
```

Comment: AFAIK `main` cannot be recursively called per C standards. Your code looks like C (and should be tagged as such). Indeed, to add e.g. new lines in the middle of a file, you have to code a program which read all the file and write all of it. At last, I don't understand what is your exact question. ("Correct my homework" is not a valid one).

Comment: Its Visual C++ but the website won't allow me to tag it under that...I'm asking help how to edit the statement inside the file..because the program I made is unacceptable..I'm just showing how my program works..and was wondering if someone can help me redo it.

Comment: Your compiler is Visual C++, but your code looks like *C*, not *C++*

Comment: okey okey...I won't argue anymore -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a real edition of a file, you probably want to keep all the file contents in memory. This is reasonable for small to medium size files (i.e. less than 1 or 2 gigabyte files on a recent laptop).

You may want to keep an array of line pointers. The array itself, and each pointer to a line inside it, would be heap-allocated.

You could have the array, its used length, and its allocated size:

```
char** linarr; // heap-allocated array of lines
unsigned nblines; // used length, i.e. number of lines
unsigned size;  // allocated size of linarr;
```

At initialization, you pre-allocate it, e.g. with

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE 100
linarr = calloc (INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof(char*));
if (!linarr)  { perror("calloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
size = INITIAL_SIZE;
nblines = 0;
```

Then you need a loop to read each line, growing the array when needed

```
FILE* inputf = fopen(filename, "rt");
// code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19331746/841108
if (!inputf) { perror("fopen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
while (!feof (inputf)) {
   // grow the array when full
   if (nblines >= size) { 
       unsigned newsize = 5*size/4 + 10;
       char**newarr = calloc(newsize, sizeof(char*));
       if (!newarr) { perror("calloc newarr"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
       for (unsigned ix=0; ix<nblines; ix++) 
         newarr[ix] = linarr[ix];
       free (linarr);
       linarr = newarr;
       size = newsize;
   };
   char* curline = NULL;
   size_t curlinesize = 0;
   if (getline(&curline, &curlinesize, inputf)<0)
      { perror("getline"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
   linarr[nblines] = curline;
   nblines++;
};
fclose (inputf); 
inputf = NULL;
```

At last you need to insert the lines appropriately (inside the growing `linarr`, updating `nblines` etc...) and write the new file (or its new content). I leave that to you.

BTW, if you coded in C++ (not in C), you could just use `std::vector<std::string>`

And if you just want to append to an existing file, not to edit it (i.e. change it in the middle) you could, as commented by [Arpit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637679/arpit), just use the append mode `"a+"` to `fopen`. But your question mentioned *editing* (not appending to) a file, and that generally requires having all the file contents in memory, organized in a suitable data structure.

<sup>PS: I know nothing about Windows, I tried to code against standards, notably Posix and C99</sup>

Comment: From the code of OP it looks like he is trying to append a text at the end. So opening file in `a+` mode will be sufficient.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this..
and nope I'm not appending a file..

Comment: sad to say again I can't vote up..it say I need 15 rep.
and again I only have 1 rep.

Comment: already accepted.. 46 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

From your program code it looks like you are appending a text instead of editing. So it will be easy for you if you can open the file in append mode(`a+`).

To make your program work you need to append your new data with old data before writing it in file.

```
printf("\nPlease Type the new statement");
    int c;            
    printf("\nInput Statement:\n");
    c=getch();
    while(c != '`'){  //use ` to quit writing.
        count++;    
        olddata[count]=c; //extending the olddata array with new data.
        }
    printf("\nDo you want to save the changes?");
    printf("\n Press[Y] YES \t\t Press[N] NO");
    printf("\n Your choice:");
    scanf("%s",&choice);
    if(choice == 'Y'|| choice == 'y')
    {
        fp =fopen(filename,"w");
        fprintf(fp,"%s",olddata);
        fclose(fp);
        main(); //this is not good. use return instead.
    }
```

If you want to avoid taking the backup of current file data in array then you need to open the file in `a+` mode.

Note: This is not an editing program, It's for appending the text at the end. If you want true editing then look at the @Basile answer.

Another example

```
int main()
{
    FILE* f=fopen("main.c","a+");
    int c;
    c=getc(f);
    while(c!=EOF){
        putchar(c);
        c=getc(f);
    }
    prinf("\n Start entering your new content \n");
    c=getchar();
    while (c != '`'){
        fputc(c,f);
        c=getchar();
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better use `putchar(c)` instead of `printf("%c",c)`

Comment: Oh! yeah it will be bit efficient then printf. is that the only reason ?

Comment: `putchar` is lower-level and more readable source code in that case.